# deprecated warnings when using sonata admin bundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, admin, sonata

I am using symfony2.7 with sonata admin doctrine orm bundle, I followed the official install instructions, works fine except one thing. At every request I get the following debrecated warnings, and I dont know how to eliminate it.

```
Date:   2016-10-18 08:58:28
Fatal: array(
    ['type'] => 16384, 
    ['message'] => 'This class is deprecated since 3.2 and will be removed with the 4.0 release.Use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Block\Service\AbstractBlockService instead.', 
    ['file'] => '/www/managedoc/branch/hoffereka/app/cache/superadmin_dev/classes.php', 
    ['line'] => 8575, 
)
```

edit: I attached a stack trace

```
1 in classes.php line 9354
2 at require_once() in ClassCollectionLoader.php line 96
3 at ClassCollectionLoader::load(array('Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener', 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage', 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\PhpBridgeSessionStorage', 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\NativeFileSessionHandler', 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\AbstractProxy', 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\SessionHandlerProxy', 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session', 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\GlobalVariables', 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference', 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateNameParser', 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\TemplateLocator', 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator', 'Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext', 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Router', 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\RedirectableUrlMatcher', 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router', 'Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator', 'Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler', 'Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event', 'Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher', 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener', 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener', 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver', 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\KernelEvent', 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent', 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent', 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent', 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent', 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent', 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents', 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Config\FileLocator', 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerNameParser', 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver', 'Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AccessMap', 'Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall', 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface', 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager', 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage', 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManager', 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker', 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface', 'Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security\FirewallMap', 'Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security\FirewallContext', 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestMatcher', 'Twig_Environment', 'Twig_Extension', 'Twig_Extension_Core', 'Twig_Extension_Escaper', 'Twig_Extension_Optimizer', 'Twig_LoaderInterface', 'Twig_Markup', 'Twig_Template', 'Monolog\Formatter\FormatterInterface', 'Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter', 'Monolog\Handler\HandlerInterface', 'Monolog\Handler\AbstractHandler', 'Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler', 'Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler', 'Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossedHandler', 'Monolog\Handler\FilterHandler', 'Monolog\Handler\TestHandler', 'Monolog\Logger', 'Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger', 'Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\DebugHandler', 'Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossed\ActivationStrategyInterface', 'Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossed\ErrorLevelActivationStrategy', 'Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\DefaultValueSupplier', 'Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Factory\AssetFactory', 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer', 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\FileCacheReader', 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\PhpParser', 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Reader', 'Doctrine\Common\Lexer', 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ConnectionRegistry', 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Proxy', 'Doctrine\Common\Util\ClassUtils', 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry', 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener', 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener', 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DateTimeParamConverter', 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter', 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterInterface', 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterManager', 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener', 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener', 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener', 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ConfigurationAnnotation', 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\BooleanType', 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\CollectionType', 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DateRangeType', 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DateTimeRangeType', 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\EqualType', 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\ImmutableArrayType', 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\TranslatableChoiceType', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BaseBlockService', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockLoaderChain', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockLoaderInterface', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockRenderer', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockRendererInterface', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockServiceInterface', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockServiceManager', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockServiceManagerInterface', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Loader\ServiceLoader', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Service\EmptyBlockService', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Service\RssBlockService', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Service\MenuBlockService', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Service\TextBlockService', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Exception\BlockExceptionInterface', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Exception\BlockNotFoundException', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Exception\Filter\DebugOnlyFilter', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Exception\Filter\FilterInterface', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Exception\Filter\IgnoreClassFilter', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Exception\Filter\KeepAllFilter', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Exception\Filter\KeepNoneFilter', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Exception\Renderer\InlineDebugRenderer', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Exception\Renderer\InlineRenderer', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Exception\Renderer\MonkeyThrowRenderer', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Exception\Renderer\RendererInterface', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Exception\Strategy\StrategyManager', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Exception\Strategy\StrategyManagerInterface', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Form\Type\ServiceListType', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BaseBlock', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\Block', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockManagerInterface', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\EmptyBlock', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Twig\Extension\BlockExtension', 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Twig\GlobalVariables', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdminExtension', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminExtensionInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminHelper', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\BaseFieldDescription', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\FieldDescriptionCollection', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\FieldDescriptionInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Pool', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Block\AdminListBlockService', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Builder\DatagridBuilderInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Builder\FormContractorInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Builder\ListBuilderInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Builder\RouteBuilderInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Builder\ShowBuilderInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\Datagrid', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\Pager', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\PagerInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQueryInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Exception\ModelManagerException', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Exception\NoValueException', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Filter\Filter', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Filter\FilterFactory', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Filter\FilterFactoryInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Filter\FilterInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\DataTransformer\ArrayToModelTransformer', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\DataTransformer\ModelsToArrayTransformer', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\DataTransformer\ModelToIdTransformer', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\EventListener\MergeCollectionListener', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Extension\Field\Type\FormTypeFieldExtension', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\AdminType', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\ChoiceType', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\DateRangeType', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\DateTimeRangeType', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\DateTimeType', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\DateType', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\DefaultType', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\NumberType', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelReferenceType', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelType', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelListType', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Guesser\TypeGuesserChain', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Guesser\TypeGuesserInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Model\AuditManager', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Model\AuditManagerInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Model\AuditReaderInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Model\ModelManagerInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\AdminPoolLoader', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\DefaultRouteGenerator', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\PathInfoBuilder', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\QueryStringBuilder', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteGeneratorInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Acl\Permission\AdminPermissionMap', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Acl\Permission\MaskBuilder', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Handler\AclSecurityHandler', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Handler\AclSecurityHandlerInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Handler\NoopSecurityHandler', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Handler\RoleSecurityHandler', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Handler\SecurityHandlerInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Translator\BCLabelTranslatorStrategy', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Translator\FormLabelTranslatorStrategy', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Translator\LabelTranslatorStrategyInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Translator\NativeLabelTranslatorStrategy', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Translator\NoopLabelTranslatorStrategy', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Translator\UnderscoreLabelTranslatorStrategy', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Twig\Extension\SonataAdminExtension', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Util\AdminAclManipulator', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Util\AdminAclManipulatorInterface', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Util\FormBuilderIterator', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Util\FormViewIterator', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Util\ObjectAclManipulator', 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Util\ObjectAclManipulatorInterface'), '/www/managedoc/branch/hoffereka/app/cache/superadmin_dev', 'classes', true, false, '.php') in bootstrap.php.cache line 2609
4 at Kernel->doLoadClassCache('classes', '.php') in bootstrap.php.cache line 2444
5 at Kernel->boot() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2478
6 at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 34
7 at require_once('/www/managedoc/branch/hoffereka/web/app_dev.php') in app_superadmin_dev.php line 3
```

Comment: Sounds like you need the new version of sonata.

Comment: This is the newest which comes from packagist when I follow the official documentation:

`composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle`

Comment: This is because they're working on a new version (their current master branch will be the 4.0 version), and they're warning you that the class you're using will be removed and that you should use `Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Block\Service\AbstractBlockService` instead in order to not have issue when you will update the bundle version.

Comment: But where and how should I use? I only configured the admin bundle in yamel files and a couple of Admin classes which are inherited from Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin. I never use any blcokservice explicitly, I cannot change it unfortulanely, but our deploy breaks because of deprecated warnings. Wouldn't it be better to deprecate something _after_ they provided and used internally an alternative?

Comment: The class will be removed, so after the depecrated warning will be useless. Maybe they have provided an alternative, have you check their master documentation or their changelog to see if they indicate what changes to do in order to keep compatibility? If you don't find anything, going back to the 3.8 version would probably remove the deprecated warning.

Comment: Deprecated since 3.2 so I don't think falling back to 3.8 would solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is not necessarily your fault. As you can see here, the problem comes from a deprecation in the block bundle. Maybe the admin bundle (or some other bundle) is using it for some purpose and hasn't yet followed the deprecation recommendation.

[Let's first fix the errors in the deprecation messages and make them more precise](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBlockBundle/pull/337).

Digging more, you can see that [3.9.0 is supposed to fix this problem](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/75a8c1d8ef1ced56d50d4ce5a188d5f7843ca2c5/CHANGELOG.md#390---2016-10-06).

Can you run `composer info` to show us what version of the admin bundle you use?

Comment: `name     : sonata-project/admin-bundle
descrip. : The missing Symfony Admin Generator
keywords : Admin Generator, admin, bootstrap, sonata
versions : * 3.9.0`

Comment: Ok so maybe it comes from another bundle? The best would be to have a stack trace… to get one, open the deprecated class(es) where you can find the exact error message you can get, and add `throw new Exception('this class should not be called')` you should be able to get a stack trace with that. If you do, edit your question to add the stack trace.

Comment: Oh wait, I think it is, let me check something.

Comment: I think I found (one of ?) the culprit(s) https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBlockBundle/blob/3.x/DependencyInjection/SonataBlockExtension.php#L277 Can you try removing this line(s) ?

Comment: You are awesome, the deprecated message gone. I create a pull request... Thanks very much!