# sonata AdminBlockServiceInterface deprecations for clear installation of symfony 2.8 + sonata 3.10

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I have clear installation of symfony 2.8 + fos user 2 + "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.10"  and see some strange deprecations

> This class is deprecated since 3.2 and will be removed with the 4.0 release.Use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Block\Service\AdminBlockServiceInterface instead

[image: log]

Is it normal? Does anybody know can I fix or mute them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deprecated warnings when using sonata admin bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101753/deprecated-warnings-when-using-sonata-admin-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** : Your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101753/deprecated-warnings-when-using-sonata-admin-bundle), ignore the rest of my answer, and update your sonata packages.

I think this is a bug, we probably forgot to remove the deprecated class (or is it an interface?) from [the class cache](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBlockBundle/blob/3.x/DependencyInjection/SonataBlockExtension.php#L274). You should file a bug report. Also, we should obviously improve the deprecation message to indicate which class we are talking about. If you feel like it, submit a PR. I must say this issue feels very familiar to me, are you sure you are using the latest version of the block bundle?

Comment: I saw that question and thought to reply to that post but I considered it would be irrelevant , cause my deprecation text differs. And it has been said that " 3.9.0 is supposed to fix this problem" but I use 3.10. I agree it's quite similar but what exactly is duplicated?

Answer (score -2):

Unless you are using version 4.0 of Symfony, just treat as a warning.

Comment: 4.0 refers to Sonata here. And what do you mean by "treat it as a warning"?

Comment: It's shown as a **deprecation** not an error! Why would you treat that with any urgency. This does indicate it should work.